# Executar função ao perder foco de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Tenho um input normal no html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style=" width: 20%" id="hLane1"> </input>
```

Para fazer com que ele execute um evento basta eu usar o evento `click`

Mas e se eu precisar executar uma outra ação quando o usuario clicar fora do  input?

Preciso que quando a seleção saia desse imput uma função seja executada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) que é disparado quando um elemento perde o foco, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
let el = document.getElementById("hLane1");

el.onblur = function(){
   console.log("blur", "saiu do input" , this);
   /// ; utilizando desta forma o this aqui dentro sera o input
}
el.onfocus = function(){
   console.log("focus", "focou no input");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" style=" width: 20%" id="hLane1"> </input>
```

Uma das vantagens de utilizar o `onblur` ao invés de um `onclik` fora do `input` é que se o usuário estiver navegando através da tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> esse evento também sera disparado.

Answer (score 8):

O próprio `Javascript` tem a função `onblur` que executa determinada ação ou função quando o `input` perder o foco (ser clicado fora):

```js
function teste(){
  console.log('teste')
}
```

```html
<input onblur="teste()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Como complemento aqui vai a versão em jQuery:

```js
$( "#hLane1" ).blur(_ => { alert( "Hoje é sexta ^.^ " ); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" style=" width: 20%" id="hLane1"> </input>
```

Documentação jQuery
[.blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função .on como múltiplos eventos e utilizar o click e o blur para fazer isso:

```js
$('.teste').on({
  click: function () {
    console.log('Fui clicado!')
  },
  blur: function() {
    console.log("Sai do input")
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="teste" placeholder="Escreva aqui...">
```